# Paging with OData vs regular parameter based paging

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata, paging

For an application which doesn't require any other OData capabilities, where paging is implemented with parameters on controller, will it be right to include OData to use the paging features of it. If I understood concept wrong please educate me.

Comment: What do you mean with 'will it be right to include OData'. What exactly is your question?

Comment: I mean just for paging purpose is it worth to include Odata in to project, I asked this because I suggested my team lead OData and he didn't show interest about it saying that we would not need querying features of Odata, however there is parameter paging being done.

Comment: Paging is such a small part of the OData framework that including OData just for the paging seems like overkill to me. All OData paging does is add `$count`, `$top` and `$skip`, these simply use the `IQueryable` methods: `Count()`, `Take(int)` and `Skip(int)`. You can probably implement this functionality yourself using those methods.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your suggestion, your opinion is helpful